# Is it possible to create an extension method to format a string?

Tags: c#, formatting, extension-methods

the question is really simple. How do we format strings in C#? this way:

```
 string.Format("string goes here with placeholders like {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
```

Now, is it possible to create an extension method to do it this way?

```
 "string goes here {0} {1}".Format(firstName, lastName);
```

That's all.

Comment: Yeah, of course I tried to make it, but I couldn't ;)

Comment: Show what you tried. Show what problem you encountered.

Comment: This questions seems to imply that you haven't tried to write your own extension method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, it's more complicated than it looks. Others say this is possible, and I don't doubt them, but it doesn't seem to be the case in Mono.

There, the standard overloads of the `Format()` method seem to take precedence in the name resolution process, and compilation fails because a static method ends up being called on an object instance, which is illegal.

Given this code:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Format(this string str, params object[] args)
    {
        return String.Format(str, args);
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("string goes here {0} {1}".Format("foo", "bar"));
    }
}
```

The Mono compiler (mcs 2.10.2.0) replies with:

> foo.cs(15,54): error CS0176: Static
>   member `string.Format(string, object)'
>   cannot be accessed with an instance
>   reference, qualify it with a type name
>   instead

Of course, the above compiles cleanly if the extension method is not named `Format()`, but maybe you actually want to use that name. If that's the case, then it's not possible, or at least not on all implementations of the .NET platform.

Comment: I receive the same error using the Microsoft compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible:

```
public static class StringFormatExtensions {
  public static string Format(this string formatStr, params object[] args) {
    return string.Format(formatStr, args);
  }
}
```

It would be good to add overloads for cases of one and two arguments.

Overall however, I don't see much value to this.

Comment: I see a lot of value in it.  Usually the first thing I start typing is a string.  **Then**, some time before finishing, I realize I'm going to want to substitute some values in.  Rather than having to go back to the beginning and wrap it all in `string.Format` I instead finish the string, including all the substitution characters as I type, and then invoke the extension method upon it.  IMO, a far more natural workflow.

Comment: It is a matter of taste. I myself implemented a similar method for string.IsNullOrEmpty so I guess the value is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Well, there is a problem. If we name the extension method as *Format*, compiler says that Format method is not accessible through an instance and we should use a type to access it. Seems that compiler gets puzzled because of name conflicts with original string.Format method.

Comment: @Kirk it's also a matter of which tools you use tools like resharper will tell you if your format string and argument count match. Wrap it up too much and you loose that

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  You'd always want to verify source is not null, of course, left that out for brevity.  [Update] turns out even though you can mimic string.Format's overloads for 1, 2, and 3 args, behind the scenes the string.Format() overloads for 1, 2, and 3 args use the varg list overload anyway...  So removed the overloads.

```
public static class FormatExtension
{
    public static string Format(this string source, params object[] args)
    {
        return string.Format(source, args);
    }
}
```

As an aside, while we show that this is possible, be careful what you extend.  The main thing here is that .Format() really only has meaning on strings that have format parameters.  This makes it much clearer to use string.Format() instead because then the arguments are obviously things Format() wants and should be in the correct form.  Having .Format() as an extension method, though, can lose some meaning since it will appear on any string regardless of whether formatting is truly valid on it or not.  Just a minor point though.

Comment: .... why would you do that with an parameter list instead of the single params arguments?

Comment: are you refering to the 1, 2, 3 arg overloads?  This is mimicking existing string.Format.  It's just a bit of a optimization so it doesn't create an args list in memory if you only need it for 1, 2, or 3 args.

Comment: @James Michael Hare: What? It's just calling the `params` overload anyway.

Comment: OIC, you mean behind the scenes in System.String.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
public static string Format(this string str, string firstItem, string secondItem)
{
    return string.Format(str, firstItem, secondItem);
}
```

BTW, this method has to belong to a `public` and `static` class.

Comment: This is correct for the case OP presented (2 params). User can learn and infer the rest. Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't DV but I would assume timing since it's a nearly exact copy of an answer... Actually your answer looks FIRST, I'm extremely confused. I'm upvoting.

Comment: I'm sure I was here very first, really. @James' answer is the most complete, but I was here first :)

Comment: It can be really hard too as sometimes you're in the middle of typing an answer and someone comes in first but you don't know till after you submitted.

Comment: This method will not compile unless, of course, the variables firstName and lastName are declared globally!  And then it would ignore the values passed into the method.

Comment: People only accept compilable answers these days :) Jeez :) Fixed it

Comment: I know, I know, that's what they tell me at work!  I have to only check in code that will build!  It's so inconvenient!  :P  However, I was referring to the fact that the arguments to your method are called "firstItem" and "secondItem" but you do not use them in your call to string.Format

Answer (score 1):

sure...

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string FormatThis(this string format, params object[] args)
    {
        return string.Format(format, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, not sure why either.  That's odd.  Maybe it was a mis-click by someone?

Comment: perhaps because my answers wasn't terribly thorough?  Do answers that are simple how-to's require a thorough answer?

Comment: It was actually downvoted because it won't work - the compiler gives precedence to the static `String.Format` method when deciding which method to call, and it results in a compiler error: `Member 'string.Format(string, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

Answer (score 1):

You should always pass an `IFormatProvider` to `String.Format`, such as `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

I like to use this set of extension methods:

```
public static class GlobalizedFormatting
{
    public static string Format(this string format, IFormatProvider provider, params object[] args)
    {
        return String.Format(provider, format, args);
    }

    public static string FormatInvariant(this string format, params object[] args)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, args);
    }

    public static string FormatCurrent(this string format, params object[] args)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, format, args);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
"{0} {1} {2}".Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "A", "B", "C");

"{0} {1} {2}".FormatInvariant("A", "B", "C");

"{0} {1} {2}".FormatCurrent("A", "B", "C");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
("string goes here {0} {1}").Format(firstName, lastName);
```

Yes you can. But what the purpose it will solve?

Comment: Extension methods are just cool, tidy, clean and handy in programming. That's just a coding style prefer. No technical advantage is sought here. :)

Comment: The purpose is putting the operand that is to be formatted ahead of the operation that is doing the formatting.  You might as well ask why we use `list.Where()` rather than `Enumerable.Where(list)`.

Comment: So you mean we should get rid of all static methods in framework and extend them just for purpose user likes writing this way.

Comment: @Kirk Woll +1 that is exactly the reason I write 90% of the extension methods I create which is to help create plain text English readable DSLs. | @hungryMind ALL is a strong word (also there's times you can't even use an extension method if you want to), but for almost all intensive purposes static methods at this point are easily a code smell if they're public. Any public static method in my code is almost certainly an extension method. There are notable exceptions like Root objects in some fluent interface DSLs.

Comment: @hungryMind: "three copy of the same string"?  What are you talking about?  Strings are reference types and are not "copied" upon method invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Format(this string str, params object[] args)
    {
        return String.Format(str, args);
    }
}
```

and should using as below:

```
Console.WriteLine("format string {0} {1}".Format((object)"foo", "bar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes as everybody above has said. 
But the newly preferred way should be:

```
$"string goes here {firstName} {lastName}";
```