# Extension method with String.Format strange compiler error

Tags: c#, string, extension-methods, string-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to create an extension method to format a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587243/is-it-possible-to-create-an-extension-method-to-format-a-string)

I have this class:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("({0}, {1})", Name, Age);
    }
}
```

The extension method:

```
public static string Format(this string source, params object[] args)
{
    return String.Format(source, args);
}
```

And I want to test it, but I have the following strange behavior:

```
Person p = new Person() { Name = "Mary", Age = 24 };

// The following works
Console.WriteLine("Person: {0}".Format(p));
Console.WriteLine("Age: {0}".Format(p.Age));

// But this gives me a compiler error:
Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}".Format(p.Name));
```

The compiler error:

*Unable to access member 'string.Format (string, params object [])' with a reference to an instance. Qualify it with a type name.*

Why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587243/is-it-possible-to-create-an-extension-method-to-format-a-string  and its accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `p.Name` is a string, you have an ambiguous call in the third scenario:

```
string.Format(string)
```

vs.

```
{string instance}.Format(object[]);
```

The resolver chooses the method that fits the signature best (in your case a `string` vs. an `object[]`) over the extension method.

You can solve the problem by either renaming the extension method, or by casting the second parameter to an object to prevent the resolver from choosing the static method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}".Format((object)p.Name));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created an extension method with the same signature as an existing method ([String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)). You will need to use a different name for your extension method. Something like FormatWith(...) instead.

I stand corrected. I just put together a unit test to verify this behavior and was unable to call "some string".Format(...). In C#, the compiler gives me a "Cannot access static method 'Format' in non-static context". Given this, I am guessing you have managed to confuse the compiler.

Comment: String.Format is a static method of the String class, p.Name is the property of my class. How can this create an error based on methods signature? Can you explain better?

Comment: static methods cannot be called from instances, hence the exception the OP is getting.

Comment: This is what I get for not having a compiler handy. I have edited my answer to reflect what a quick unit test should have told me before hand.